# quadratic twists of $P_{\mathbb{Q}}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have seen somewhere else that if $C$ is a conic in $P_{\mathbb{Q}}^2$,then it is a quadratic twist of $P_{\mathbb{Q}}^1$.

So I want to know how to define the quadratic twist of $P_{\mathbb{Q}}^2$(maybe for a general variety?) and why is this curve isomorphic to $C$(as an algebraic variety)?

Thanks!

Comment: The general phrase you are looking for (i.e. twists/forms of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$) are the so-called *Brauer-Severi varieties*. Googling that should give you more than ample literature. If you want a specific reference I think that the book of Szamuely and Gille on central simple algebras and/or Poonen's *Rational points on varieties* are a good place to start. You won't, in general, just get quadratic twists. This is a coincidence of the one-dimensional case.

Comment: Small point: A conic over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a twist of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ necessarily. A smooth   conic over $\mathbb{Q}$ is though.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thanks! This is important. I always think casually and write rigorously.